# Swift: My custom UITableViewDataSource class thinks it doesn't conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have checked a few other questions out there, of which the answers seem to be in the datasource methods' declarations. However, I cannot find what's wrong with my methods declarations.

Here is my class:

```
import UIKit

class GuestControl: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var leftTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightTable: UITableView!
    var userList = [User]() //even numbers including 0 go on the left table, odd numbers go on the

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //Here is where we link to that user's contact page
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: GuestTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("guestCell") as! GuestTableViewCell

    if tableView == leftTable {
        cell.configureCellWithUser(userList[indexPath.row+indexPath.row])
    } else {
        cell.configureCellWithUser(userList[indexPath.row+indexPath.row+1])
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let num = Double(userList.count) / 2.0
    if tableView == leftTable {
        return Int(round(num)) //round up
    } else {
        return Int(num) //round down
    }
}
```

}

And here is the exact error:

```
Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' with type '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
Candidate is not '@objc', but protocol requires it
Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' with type '(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell'
Candidate is not '@objc', but protocol requires it
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to subclass UIViewController. class GuestControl: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the protocol requires that the table view data source methods are "Objective-C compatible". This can be achieved by

- making your class inherit from `NSObject` (or any `NSObject` subclass)

  ```
  class GuestControl: NSObject, ...
  ```
- or adding the `@objc` attribute to the class definition

  ```
  @objc class GuestControl:  ...
  ```
- or adding the `@objc` attribute to the data source methods

  ```
  @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ...
  ```

In the first two cases, *all* methods of the class are made Objective-C
compatible.

If a (table) view controller is used as the table view data source then this automatically satisfied because `UI(Table)ViewController` inherits
from `NSObject`.

Comment: I inherited from NSObject, and the problem went away. Thank you!